# Is there a way to "carry around" my own sh functions inside linux terminals, without having to install a file everywhere I connect?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I'd like to make so that wherever I go when connecting to terminals, I can use the same custom commands. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/980640/how-can-i-execute-a-script-on-a-remote-machine-over-ssh-but-source-local-files)

Answer (score 0):

With bash, it used to be possible to do this using [exported functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-export), which end up in the environment.  It turned up [you could use this against CGI-based web services](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2014-6271), and, over SSH, against many Git hosting solutions, so this capability was heavily restricted in bash.

Consequently, I do not think what you are asking is possible anymore, at least not without reconfiguring the SSH servers and potentially patching their sources.